# Applying trigger on sqlite database in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, triggers

How can I apply a trigger on my sqlite database using objective-c.

I want to apply trigger to check if a table has performed an insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

Run a [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) statement on it.  You'll need to find some way to check the trigger fires, so if you e.g. make the trigger insert rows into another table, you can regularly check the table to see if it has new rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table named CSAppointment, the you can write:

`ALTER TABLE "CSAppointment" ADD COLUMN  "tableUid" INTEGER;
CREATE TRIGGER log_insert AFTER INSERT ON CSAppointment
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CSRowChanges(tableUId, rowUid, deleteFlag ) VALUES (NEW.tableUid, NEW.uid, 0 );
END;
CREATE TRIGGER log_update AFTER UPDATE ON CSAppointment
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CSRowChanges(tableUId, rowUid, deleteFlag) VALUES (NEW.tableUid, NEW.uid, 0) ;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER log_delete AFTER DELETE ON CSAppointment
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CSRowChanges(tableUId, rowUid, deleteFlag) VALUES (OLD.tableUid, OLD.uid, 1 ) ;
END;`

This way you are adding triggers for insert, update and delete operations.

More information on [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/).